# Combine Two Tables Into A Third Based Upon A Number Match

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I'd like to combine two tables into a new table but only on the condition that there is a match on two different columns. I need to generate a CSV file that containing combined rows of data from the two different tables.  Below explains in better detail

There are two tables.   One is called "user" which contains user info and the other is called "project_details" which contains project details.  I'd like to create a csv file that merges the "user" data adjacent (appended to the far right) to the record project_details data based upon a match of the user_id.
In other words its shows combines the records only if there is a user_id match.

```
Table Name = user  This table contains simple table information
id          name        
1           Bill            
2           Steve       
3           Joe
```

---

```
Table Name = project_details
project_name        color       userid
House Project       blue        2
```

---

THE SQL RESULT

```
Table Name = combined_info
project_name        color       name    userid
House Project       blue        Steve   2
```

The command creates a new table and fills it with both tables if the "id" column in the tabled called "user" matches the column called "userid" in "project_details.

Is this possible with MySQL?  If so what command would do it?

Maybe there no need to create a new table? The path of least resistance is always the best.

I can not thank you enough in advance for your kind logic on this question.

Answer (score 1):

Your base query would look like

```
SELECT p.project_name,
       p.color,
       u.name,
       p.userid
  FROM project p JOIN
       user u ON p.userid = u.id
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2aeca/1)**

Now, if you want to create a CSV file then you can use [`INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html) clause

```
SELECT p.project_name,
       p.color,
       u.name,
       p.userid
  INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/mydata.csv'
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
       LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
   FROM project p JOIN
       user u ON p.userid = u.id
```

*IMHO there is no point in creating an additional table to achieve your goal*

Comment: I agree.  No need for the extra clutter.  Thanks peterm!

Comment: @ScottFichter You're welcome! If it was what you were looking for please, consider to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer.